# result show with html tags when print using php

Tags: php, tags

I have got a string contain with html tags.I want to print it using php , but it print with html tags.How to print somethings like this?

**String :**

```
<p style="color:#f00">HTML basic test Text</p>
```

**Want to show :**

HTML basic test Text

currently I show the result : `<p style="color:#f00">HTML basic test Text</p>`

Have you any solution?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Can you give us the PHP code you are using to get such output?

Answer (score 1):

Like CBroe said, you can use `strip_tags()` function

```
<?php
  $text = '<p style="color:#f00">HTML basic test Text</p>';
  echo strip_tags($text);
?>
```

Comment: I have a string which contains lots of html tags something like p tag.If I use `strip_tags` it remove all html tags and also not implemented css.

Comment: Do you want to keep some HTML tag? Do you want to keep the style (color, font,...) when printing? I'm a bit disappointed of what you really want

Comment: Yes i have a lots of tags with contains style tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT an echo should do it. If I need some HTML code to be generatet with php I echo it like:

```
<?php
    echo '<p>Hallo world</p>';
?>
```

Worked for me, I never used print for that purpose.